# EditTextPreference, how to save value as float

Tags: android, preferences

How can i save value as float from EditTextPreference?

I follow this [PreferenceActivity: save value as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721358/preferenceactivity-save-value-as-integer)
But i did not work for me.
my preference file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Taxes"
    android:key="first_category">

    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="include_taxes"
        android:summary="Include or Exclude taxes"
        android:title="Include Taxes" 
        android:defaultValue="true"
    />
<PreferenceScreen 
    android:key="Entering_Taxes"
    android:title="Enter the Values"
    android:dependency="include_taxes"
    android:persistent="false">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="ED_tax"
            android:title="E.D Tax" 
            android:summary="Define E.D Tax"
            android:dialogTitle="Set E.D Tax"
            android:dialogMessage="Enter the value" 
            android:defaultValue='7.30'/>

    </PreferenceScreen> 
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have to add all values of taxes.

Comment: Maybe you could add some code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

say you can get string of editTextPreference like this,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String value = preferences.getString("SomeKey", "");
```

so convert that string to float like this:

```
float f = Float.valueOf(value);
```