# Android Preferences error, "String cannot be cast to int"

Tags: java, android, string, integer, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to setup a preferences activity but my app keeps crashing and I get the following logcat:

> > FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appthing.myapp/com.appthing.myapp.Main}:
> >     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
> >     java.lang.Integer
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.Integer 07-24 16:37:59.556: E/AndroidRuntime(17384):
>   at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)

In my `Main` activity I have the following code inside the `onResume()` method:

```
    SeekBar tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.tipSeekBar);
    SeekBar splitSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.splitSeekBar);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    tipSeekBar.setProgress(preferences.getInt("defaultTip", 15));
    splitSeekBar.setProgress(preferences.getInt("defaultSplit", 1));
    tipSeekBar.setMax(preferences.getInt("maxTip", 25));
    splitSeekBar.setMax(preferences.getInt("maxSplit", 10));
```

Here is what I have in the Preference class (as requested):

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
// I was told in tutorials this is all I need in the oncreate method
```

I don't understand why its saying something about a string. All my values are integers and I am using `android:inputType="number"` to make sure only an int can be entered. I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the app to clear the cache and nothing works.

### *RESOLVED:*

**"Your Preferences in XML, even if you set android:inputType="number" are still stored as a String"** (by [Waza_Be](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327402/waza-be)). 
All I had to do is do `Integer.parseInt()` to grab the correct value.

Comment: Can you see the stack trace at what line of calling getInt it is failing? Is it tipSeekBar or splitSeekBar Etc.

Comment: Can you post how you are storing the values in preferences?

Comment: Which line in your code is throwing this exception?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your Preferences in XML, even if you set `android:inputType="number"` are still stored as a String

You have 2 choices:

1) the 'not-so-nice': `Integer.parseInt( preferences.getString("defaultTip", "15"));`

2) Using your own type of Integer Preference. More complicated to set in first place but really better (similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755608/327402)

Comment: "Your Preferences in XML, even if you set android:inputType="number" are still stored as a String" thats the key, I never knew this! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: Well, that's quite silly. Especially when your ListPreferences are referencing an <integer-array>, it still treats them as Strings. Thanks for the  tip.

Comment: I set string value "" in shared preference for integer object, so when i get value from preference i am getting this issue, so please make sure you set value into preference is integer only.

Comment: ok, so this is the second time I have run into this, years apart, and I still have to ask - what is the *point* of `preferences.getInt` if it's just going to throw an exception?!

Answer (score 1):

The exception can also be thrown if

- you are using the same `key` for storing two or more different types of `values`
- at first you stored the value as `String` and then changed storing and retrieving implementation for `int` value. For this case just clear the cache.

Answer (score -1):

If you are storing the preferences with the right data types, then it should not be problem. Please look at the **JavaDoc** [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).