# Android preference: EditTextPreference only show string

Tags: android

In my app i have saved some values as integer.I'm going to show that values in EditTextPreference in preference page ,but  throw exception because value is int not string . is there any workaround to show(or maybe store) integer value in EditTextPreference ?

```
with(sharedPref.edit()) {

   putLong( context.getString(R.string.preference_update_date_key),Date().time)


   putInt(context.getString(R.string.preference_register_key),code)
  
 apply()
}
```

.

```
        <PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        
            <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/quiz_setting_messages_header">
        
                <EditTextPreference
                    app:key="@string/preference_update_date_key"
                    app:title="@string/date_val"      
                    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
        
                <EditTextPreference
                    app:key="@string/preference_register_key"
                    app:title="@string/regkey"
                    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
        
            </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceScreen/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PreferenceActivity: save value as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721358/preferenceactivity-save-value-as-integer)